# My Minecraft Flying machine doesn't work

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have been making a Shulkercraft Bamboo farm in MCPE but it doesn't work. I thought it was because I had the wrong version, but my friend told me that it shouldn't matter.

The machine I built goes 1 block forward and then 1 block backwards.

Here is the link for Shulkercraft Bamboo Farm

Answer (score 1):

This farm design only works on Java edition. MCPE is Bedrock edition so this design doesn't work, as redstone works differently for Bedrock.

Comment: Thnx my m8 i didn't knew that bc i only installed mcpe for 2 days

Comment: Yea. You can only get Java on PC, so if it's not on your PC, it's not Java, it's Bedrock. But you can also get Bedrock edition on your PC (Windows 10 Edition).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a flying machine that works in bedrock edition. Just add the slime blocks to it and use it in your farm.[image]